# How to execute a command in a Jenkins 2.0 Pipeline job and then return the stdout

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-workflow, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-2

Is there a better way to run a shell task in a Jenkins 2.0 pipeline and then return the `stdout` of the command.  The only way I can get this to work is to pipe the output of the command to a file and then read the file in to a variable.

```sh
sh('git config --get remote.origin.url > GIT_URL')
def stdout = readFile('GIT_URL').trim()
```

This seems like a really bad way to return the output. I was hoping I could do something like:

```sh
def stdout = sh('git config --get remote.origin.url').stdout
```

or

```sh
def exitcode = sh('git config --get remote.origin.url').exitcode
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do I get the output of a shell command executed using into a variable from Jenkinsfile (groovy)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36547680/how-to-do-i-get-the-output-of-a-shell-command-executed-using-into-a-variable-fro)

Answer (score 24):

Yes as [luka5z](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6128602/luka5z) mentioned, version 2.4 of Pipeline Nodes and Processes Plugin now supports this kind of stuff:

```
def stdout = sh(script: 'git config --get remote.origin.url', returnStdout: true)
println stdout

def retstat = sh(script: 'git config --get remote.origin.url', returnStatus: true)
println retstat
```

Seems if you try to return both in the same script, returnStatus will overwrite returnStdout which is a bit unfortunate.

You can read more in the official documentation [here](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#sh-shell-script)

Edit:
Furthermore, it allows you finer grained control over failed/unstable build statuses too. You can see an example in my comment [here](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/218866667?page=1#comment_207927687)

Comment: Can we use them together ? catch returnStdout in a variable and returnStatus in an other ? because it is not cool to repeat the sh script twice

Comment: @codeGeass How is this supposed to work? A function has exactly _one_ return value (i.e. _one_ memory place for its return value on the stack) and that's why there's also just one assignment to one variable. See also "[_In mathematics, a function is a binary relation_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics))". If you want return both (or even more, like an error msg) you have to use a complex string: CSV, JSON, XML, ...

Comment: @codeGeass See how it works at [How to return either stdout or stderr together with the status from a Jenkins Pipeline sh script step](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68967642/1744774).

Comment: I was thinking about a return output with multiples entries like map.. but now (after 4 years) I know that jenkins does not allow this :)

Answer (score 21):

### **Update**

Since 6/2016 [JENKINS-26133](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-26133) is officially marked as Resolved. Therefore, before trying below workarounds, first try supported [implementation](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#sh-shell-script) for `sh`/`bat` which makes it possible to use  `returnStdout` and `returnStatus` parameters.

### Workarounds

Unfortunately this feature is still unsupported and missing. For more information please refer to official [ticket](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-26133):

> JENKINS-26133 Shell script taking/returning output/status Status:
>   Assignee: Priority: Resolution: Open Jesse Glick Major Unresolved

---

> Description
>
> Currently sh has no meaningful return value, and throws an exception
>   if the exit status is not zero. Would be nice to have an option to
>   have it return the exit code (zero or not) as an integer value:
>
> ```
> def r = sh script: 'someCommand', returnStatus: true
> ```
>
> Current workaround:
>
> ```
> sh 'someCommand; echo $? > status' 
> def r = readFile('status').trim()
> ```
>
> Or to have it return its standard output (akin to shell backticks):
>
> ```
> def lines = sh(script: 'dumpStuff.sh', returnStdout: true).split("\r?\n")
> ```
>
> Workaround:
>
> ```
> sh 'dumpStuff.sh > result'
> def lines = readFile('result').split("\r?\n")
> ```
>
> Or to have it take something on standard input:
>
> ```
> sh script: 'loadStuff.sh', stdin: someText
> ```
>
> Workaround:
>
> ```
> writeFile file: 'input', text: someText >     sh 'loadStuff.sh < input'
> ```
>
> Probably requires some API changes in durable-task.