# Can't store sh command output through DSL (groovy) in Jenkins pipeline job

Tags: bash, curl, jenkins, groovy

I would like to get last build output in pipeline Jenkins job and attach in email (using emailext plugin). Curl works fine and gives proper build output but i can't store in variable to attach in the email. I'm using latest jenkins version.

I can see there are couple of related posts for simple sh command but that doesn't work for curl response store.

## Tried code:

1.

```
def consoleOutput = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'curl http://' + jenkinsUser + ':' + jenkinsUserToken + '@' + jenkinsServer + ':8080/job/' + 'myJob/lastBuild/consoleText').trim()
echo consoleOutput
```

2.

```
sh 'curl http://' + jenkinsUser + ':' + jenkinsUserToken + '@' + jenkinsServer + ':8080/job/' + "${env.JOB_NAME}" + '/lastBuild/consoleText; echo $? > status'
def consoleOutput = readFile('status').trim()
```

3.

```
def consoleOutput = sh(script: 'curl http://' + jenkinsUser + ':' + jenkinsUserToken + '@' + jenkinsServer + ':8080/job/' + '/myJob/lastBuild/consoleText', returnStatus: true).split("\r?\n")
echo consoleOutput
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36547680/how-to-do-i-get-the-output-of-a-shell-command-executed-using-into-a-variable-fro

Comment: I'm sorry but i tried these ways and had gone through this post as well but it doesn't work and after this build fails. It doesn't go to next line as far as execution is concerned at jenkins side. Thanks Tim!

Comment: your 1st approach should get the right result, just don't re-define the variable.

Comment: Hmm. that was type to use echo. Will try again...

Comment: We might need to see more context in your script. The problem might be elsewhere besides this line of code.

Comment: any update here?  I'm having a similar issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you're missing the inner array and some double quotes and escaped double quotes for running the script:

```
sh([ script: "curl \"http://${jenkinsUser}:${jenkinsUserToken}@${jenkinsServer}:8080/job/myJob/lastBuild/consoleText\"").trim()
```

Also there are multiple ways to do shell scripts and it depends on the **type of jenkins pipeline** you are using.

In a [jenkins declarative pipeline](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#declarative-pipeline) you need to include a `script {...}` block for all script type code and setting variables, and that would look like this:

```
pipeline { 
    agent {
        ...
    } 
    parameters {
        ...
    }
    environment {
   ...
   }
   stages {
        stage('Run Required Scripts') {
            steps {
               ...
                script {
                    NOTIFIER_BULD_NAME = sh([script: "./getNotifier.sh", returnStdout: true]).trim()
                    EMAIL_TEXT = sh([script: "./printEmailText.sh ${CURRENT_BUILD}  ${PREVIOUS_BUILD}", returnStdout: true]).trim()
                    BODY= sh([ script: "curl \"http://${jenkinsUser}:${jenkinsUserToken}@${jenkinsServer}:8080/job/myJob/lastBuild/consoleText\"").trim()
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Send Email') {
            when {
                expression {
                    // Only send when there is text.
                    "${EMAIL_TEXT}" != "";
                }
            }
            steps{
                emailext (
                    to: 'software@company.com',
                    subject: "You have mail - ${EMAIL_TEXT}",
                    body: """${NOTIFIER_BULD_NAME} - ${EMAIL_TEXT}: 
... 
${BODY}
""",
                     attachLog: false
                 )
            }
        }
    }
```

In a [Jenkins scripted pipeline](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#scripted-pipeline), you don't need a `script{}` block, you can actually put it most places. Mostly I've put it in stage blocks `stage('some stage'){...}` and I've done it like this:

```
V5_DIR = WORKSPACE + '/' + sh([script: "basename ${V5_GIT_URL} .git", returnStdout: true]).trim()
```

Although I've also used curl commands (for scripted pipelines) and didn't need the inner array...

```
lastSuccessfulCommit = sh(
     script: "curl -sL --user ${JENKINS_API_USER}:${JENKINS_API_PSW} \"${lastSuccessfulCommitUrl}\" | sed -e 's/<[^>]*>//g'",
     returnStdout: true
)
```

And for reference, echoing vars looks like this in both

```
 sh([script: "echo \"Value: ${someVariable}\""])
```

Hopefully [this documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#working-with-the-environment) helps a bit too, but I know recently Jenkins documentation can be pretty spotty, so I also found [a great gist about how to not do things for Jenkins Declarative pipelines](https://gist.github.com/katcaola/2f18350ee66e0a3b2feb57a2992643c3). Good luck!