# Get SVN commit username in jenkins pipeline script

Tags: email, jenkins, svn, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm setting up a jenkins ci server. In my pipeline script, where I checkout the latest svn repository of our project, I want to get the user who last committed to the repository, so I can send an email to that specific user if something went wrong.
Is there a function in the svn plugin for jenkins to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a '`sh`' step inside your stage.
This will print the user of the last commit.

```
svn log -l 1 --quiet | grep "^r" | awk '{print $3}'
```

Comment: i knew that already, but i want to use the username as a variable in the pipeline script

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36547680/how-to-do-i-get-the-output-of-a-shell-command-executed-using-into-a-variable-fro

Answer (score 0):

Use exception handling to maintain control in the event of an svn failure.

```
try {
    def username = sh(script:'svn log -l 1 --quiet | awk -F\'|\' \'/^r/ { print $2 }\'', returnStdout:true).trim()
} catch (Exception ex) {
    println("Unable to fetch svn username: ${ex}")
    // use error("message") if you need to fail the build
}
```