# How to save the output of an sh to a Groovy variable?

Tags: shell, jenkins, groovy

I need to store the output of this command into a variable:

```
sh "curl -s 'http://nexus-cicd.stgcloud.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.xml' | grep '<version>.*</version>' | sort --version-sort | uniq | tail -n1 | sed -e 's#\\(.*\\)\\(<version>\\)\\(.*\\)\\(</version>\\)\\(.*\\)#\\3#g'"
```

I tried the following, but echo output null

```
parentLast = sh ("curl -s 'http://nexus-cicd.stgcloud.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.xml' | grep '<version>.*</version>' | sort --version-sort | uniq | tail -n1 | sed -e 's#\\(.*\\)\\(<version>\\)\\(.*\\)\\(</version>\\)\\(.*\\)#\\3#g'")
echo "$parentLast"
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36547680/how-to-do-i-get-the-output-of-a-shell-command-executed-using-into-a-variable-fro

Comment: Please use the format `sh (script: "<command>", returnStdout: true).trim()`.