# How to set ENV variables inside a Jenkinsfile with sh() command

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy

Jenkinsfile contents:

```
pipeline {
  environment {
    SOMEVAR = "${sh(returnStdout: true, script: "node -p -e "require('./package.json').version")}"
  }
}
```

Throws an error about unexpected char.

Just tried:

```
SOMEVAR = /${sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'echo 1234')}/
```

It works, but then i tried

```
SOMEVAR = /${sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'node -v')}/
```

It returned: "node: command not found"

Comment: Can you provide the error message? You have to escape chars like backslash by the way, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36547680/how-to-do-i-get-the-output-of-a-shell-command-executed-using-into-a-variable-fro?rq=1

Comment: Updated my question, in a later steps i actually can use `node` or `npm`, but  not in an environment block, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

```
script {
    env.SOMEVAR = sh script: 'node -v'
}
```

Try to put this block after 'steps {' in first stage of your pipeline. You use Declarative pipeline, not Scripted pipeline syntax.