# How can I echo the "params" object from a Jenkins build into a sed instruction in shell?

Tags: shell, jenkins, groovy, sed, scripting

I understand that the basic format is something like
echo  | sed '../../..'

I've been accessing the Jenkins params variable as such:

```
sh label: '', script: ' echo "${params}" | sed \'s/\\([[:alnum:]_][[:alnum:]_]*\\)/"\\1"/g\''
```

the "sh label" and "script" elements are from the pipeline syntax snippet generator that Jenkins provides.

Yet as an output the echo just outputs a blank line, and if I echo separately after the statement, the params variable is unchanged.

I know my regex is working perfectly as I've tested it directly on multiple strings.

I figure my error lies somewhere with **how** I'm accessing the reserved Jenkins params object, and that sed isn't accessing it as a string, rather an object (?).

I also assumed that maybe the params object wasn't saving the sed edits, so I tried storing it like so:

```
def params = sh (script: ' echo $params | sed \'s/\\([[:alnum:]_][[:alnum:]_]*\\)/"\\1"/g\'', , returnStdout:true).trim()
```

Could someone please help, or move me in the right direction? Thanks.

Comment: Instead of using `script` , can you use embedded shell script like this:
sh '''echo $params '''

Comment: You are trying to store a shell output into a groovy variable. Refer this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36547680/how-to-do-i-get-the-output-of-a-shell-command-executed-using-into-a-variable-fro

Answer (score 0):

If you enclose the script in single quotes, the $params variable will not be expanded, so you're running the sed command over the string literal '$params' rather than the content. Other than that, you're on the right track.

It should be something like this (I haven't tested):

```
def params = sh (script: " echo $params | sed 's/\\([[:alnum:]_][[:alnum:]_]*\\)/\"\1\"/g'", , returnStdout:true).trim()
```