# Return values from a shell script to a jenkins pipeline script

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a shell script triggered by a jenkins pipeline that detects if files have changed in a folder. I want the script to return 1 or 0 to the pipeline script depending on the changes in the folder. Also I want to read that returned value in the pipeline script, so I can take actions accordingly.

Comment: Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36547680/how-to-do-i-get-the-output-of-a-shell-command-executed-using-into-a-variable-fro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the `sh` step the `returnStdout` or `returnStatus` parameters. To my knowledge you can only pass one.

To work around this I would do something like this:

```
def result = sh script: 'my-command || echo error', returnStdout: true
def error = result.endsWith("error")
```

`error` will only be true if the script returned a non zero exit code.
`result` wil contain the output of the script (maybe including the string "error" which can be removed if necessary)