# How to use Jenkinsfile to pass BRANCH_NAME to a jenkins job

Tags: jenkins, groovy, svn, continuous-integration, devops

So I have a jenkins job that checkout a svn repo like this `remote: "svn://xyz-repo/svn/xyzclientjs/$BRANCH_NAME"]],`

I pass this $BRANCH_NAME through a Jenkinsfile that is present in this svn repo.

Now Inside Jenkinsfile I am doing this -

```
node 'xyz-169' { 

  checkout scm
  def BRANCH_NAME = sh "svn info | grep -Po 'Relative URL: \\^/\\K.*'"
  def BRANCH_REV = sh "svn info --show-item revision"

    stage('Build A') {
         build job: 'xyzclientjs-webui-test', propagate: true, parameters:
            [
              [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'BRANCH_NAME', value: $env.BRANCH_NAME],
              [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'BRANCH_REV', value: $env.BRANCH_REV],
            ]
```

But when I run the job on jenkins I get following error

```
Error while checking out xyzclientjs branch from SVN
10:26:05  [Pipeline] error
10:26:05  [Pipeline] }
10:26:05  [Pipeline] // stage
10:26:05  [Pipeline] }
10:26:05  [Pipeline] // node
10:26:05  [Pipeline] End of Pipeline
10:26:05  java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.ErrorStep.message expects class java.lang.String but received class groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException
```

Is there any way to do this. Please help any suggestions would be highly appriciated.

Comment: What is `checkout scm`? it is not a valid pipeline command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a look here for an example to correctly fetch the output of a sh step:

[How do I get the output of a shell command executed using into a variable from Jenkinsfile (groovy)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36547680/how-do-i-get-the-output-of-a-shell-command-executed-using-into-a-variable-from-j)

For example (not tested due to lack of SVN):

```
def BRANCH_NAME = sh (
  script: "svn info | grep -Po 'Relative URL: \\^/\\K.*'",
  returnStdout: true
).trim()
```

Comment: Thank you soooooooooooooo much for your help I highly appreciate it