# Printing null value for a variable

Tags: git, github, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

```
git checkout master
TARGET_COMMIT_ID = sh 'git log -n 1'
echo '${TARGET_COMMIT_ID}'
```

In my Jenkins file i'm executing the above commands to print the commit i'd of the target branch.
In runtime i'm seeing null value printing.
what am i missing here ?

My expectation was to print the commit i'd in the output.

Comment: If all you want is the ID of the current commit, you are not getting it the right way. `git rev-parse HEAD` should give you that... which is not directly related to your issue, but keep that in mind.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the output of a shell command executed using into a variable from Jenkinsfile (groovy)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36547680/how-do-i-get-the-output-of-a-shell-command-executed-using-into-a-variable-from-j)

Comment: Another issue here is the use of single quotes in `echo '${TARGET_COMMIT_ID}'`. Single quotes don't support string interpolation, only double-quotes or triple-double-quotes do (the linked answer does that right as well). In your example you don't even need string interpolation though, just do `echo TARGET_COMMIT_ID`  when you want to output a single variable.