# Returning PostgreSQL result from docker to groovy

Tags: postgresql, docker, jenkins

in my Jenkins pipeline I'm using docker to run `psql` to insert/select some data to database and I have problem with select. I would like to get data from database and later make some operation on these data. Problem is, that query works fine, but it's run inside docker. I have something like this:

```
def method() {
    def postgresResult
    script {
        // Run inside a Docker container
        postgresResult = docker.image("psql-client:latest").inside("--entrypoint=''") {
            withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'psql', variable: 'PGPASSWORD')]) {
                // Capture the result of the psql command and replace newlines with a delimiter
                sh """
                    psql -h {MY_HOST} -p 5432 -U user -d database -t -A -c "${selectQuery}"
                """
            }
        }
    }
    echo "postgresql... : ${postgresResult}"
}
```

In Jenkins console output, I can see returned data, but when I want to display them as data from `postgresResult` I'm getting null. Is there any option to assign returned data to `postgresResult` variable, preferably as array? The query returns only data from one column, like `AZ-1234`, `AZ-5678`, `AZ-9999` and so on.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the output of a shell command executed using into a variable from Jenkinsfile (groovy)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36547680/how-do-i-get-the-output-of-a-shell-command-executed-using-into-a-variable-from-j)

Comment: Unfortunately not, I tried using `returnStdout` and other methods, but still it doesn't work