# Get git branch name with gradle git plugin on jenkins slave

Tags: jenkins, grgit

I'm doing sonar integration and would like to pass git branch as a parameter. It will be run on Jenkins server.

Before I was using next line of code to get current git branch:

```
def workingBranch = """git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD""".execute().text.trim()
```

After I replaced it with:

```
grgit.branch.current.fullName
```

But this always gives me "HEAD". How to achieve same functionality?

Comment: Hi Eugen, were you able to resolve this?

Comment: It is not possible in this way. You should use jenkins env variables

Comment: Sorry for the really late answer, but I just stumbled upon this question. I'm not sure exactly which method applies better to your situation. But, I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am doing something very similar. As it turns out, the Git plugin in Jenkins is tuned in several ways to minimize the git clone and checkout. There are 2 ways that I've found to deal with this.

1. ***The Easy Way***

   Use Jenkins' built-in environment variables, as you already suggested in the comments.

def workingBranch = System.getenv("GIT_BRANCH") ?: grgit.branch.current.fullName

2. ***The Job Configuration Way***

   You can also set up the job  to checkout the branch as a local branch, rather than a detached HEAD. This is under "Additional Behaviors", named "Check out to specific local branch". There are many other questions that detail the settings for that, and/or the Declarative Pipeline approach, depending on what your needs.

- [Declarative Pipeline custom checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45405121/995617)
- [Configuring local branch option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45340481/995617)