# Stripping GIT_BRANCH to get the verison

Tags: jenkins

I have branch with this format: release/1.0.0

When I use ${GIT_BRANCH}, I get the following: origin/release/1.0.0

I have tried using EnvInj to set a variable like this:
[image]

If I leave ${GIT_BRANCH} the way it is it works fine, but if i use ${GIT_BRANCH, fullName=false}. It is always a empty string.

I have also tried using: [How to receive local Git branch name with Jenkins Git plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541609/how-to-receive-local-git-branch-name-with-jenkins-git-plugin)

What is correct format to get just 1.0.0.0-rc134

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always write a small bash script to get this done.

1. Use a execute shell build step

   ```
   echo "RELEASECANDIDATE=${GIT_BRANCH##*/}-rc${BUILD_NUMBER}" > ${WORKSPACE}/inject.txt
   ```
2. Use a Inject shell and in the properties file section give the file name

   ```
   ${WORKSPACE}/inject.txt
   ```
3. Finally in the update build name , use macro below variable

   ```
   ${RELEASECANDIDATE}
   ```

This should get you correct value as expected

Comment: Getting this  The given properties file path 'inject.txt' doesn't exist

Comment: The reason was the file might be getting created in some other location, i have updated the answer to create the file in jenkins workspace parent location. try the updated answer.

Comment: okay that seems to work.. however for my branch "origin/release/1.0.0" GIT_BRANCH##*/ always return empty string.

Comment: If you have followed above steps , you should get the Git branch value as 1.0.0

And add another below command in starting execute shell after the inject file step

echo ${GIT_BRANCH##*/}-rc${BUILD_NUMBER}"

And tell me the output of console and inject.txt file

Please check if u missed any of the above steps.It's working from my end

Answer (score 0):

Use below command at execute bash to get any part of the branch string you want. I am getting the mid part here. Keep in mind it starts counting from left and from 1.

```
SUBSTR=$(echo $GIT_BRANCH | cut -d'/' -f 2)
```

I continued the search and found a better solution for this problem at the link below. Basically rather than using $GIT_BRANCH, you can add one additional behaviour after git pull and "check out to specific local branch" and then use $GIT_LOCAL_BRANCH that will return what you expect and is compatible with all plugins (at least with FTP plugin that I used). Please see it in more details at the link below:

[How to receive local Git branch name with Jenkins Git plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541609/how-to-receive-local-git-branch-name-with-jenkins-git-plugin)

Answer (score 0):

Try to get `${GIT_LOCAL_BRANCH}`. It returns only branch name.